# Why run cucumber tests with tags gives error message

Tags: maven, kotlin, cucumber, pom.xml

I have a Maven project with JUnit 4 and Cucumber tests.

I want to run one test with particular tag.

When I run command in Terminal

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@Smoke"
```

or

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @Smoke"
```

I get errror message:

> [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".options=--tags @Smoke". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:. Availa
> ble lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-r
> esources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-depl
> oy. -> [Help 1]

Test Runner:

```
package step_definitions

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(Cucumber::class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = ["src/test/kotlin/features/"],
    tags = "@Smoke",
    glue = ["step_definitions"],
    plugin = ["html:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.html"]
)
class TestRunner
```

My pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
        <version>7.2.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>7.2.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>7.3.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Where can be a problem?

Comment: The [manpage](https://manpages.org/mvn) (and [this question](/questions/17332857)) list options _before_ goals such as `test`. Have you tried them in that order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue was only in one character **"** in wrong place

Correct command is:

```
mvn test -D"cucumber.filter.tags=@Smoke"
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with -Dtags = "@your_tags" yet

Comment: This command does not select correct tag, it run tests with tag that located in Test Runner

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).