# Trying to run Cucumber test via Maven and JUnit

Tags: java, maven, junit, cucumber

I am trying to build a test automation framework using Java with the following plugins : Maven, Cucumber, JUnit.

IDE that I use is IntelliJ Idea.

This is my POM.xml:

```
<groupId>org.test</groupId>
<artifactId>web-automation-java</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>web-automation-java</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.surefire/maven-surefire-common -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-common</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>7.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>7.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>7.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have a feature file with 2 simple steps, but with different tags:

```
  Feature: Feature file for test
      Description for feature file

  @smoke
  Scenario: Access google on web via @smoke layer0
    Given the browser starts
    And user is on page "https://google.ro"
    When the user waits
    Then the user should be on "Google" page

  @layer0
  Scenario: Access google on web via layer0
    Given the browser starts
    And user is on page "https://google.ro"
    When the user waits
    Then the user should be on "Google" page
```

My test runner :

```
package testRunner;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/java/features"},
        glue = {"steps"},
        monochrome = true,
        plugin = {"pretty",
                "html:src/test/reports/cucumber-html-report.html",
                "timeline:target/cucumber-timeline/",
                "json:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.json",
                "junit:target/cucumber-report/report-xml.xml"},
        dryRun = false,
        useFileNameCompatibleName = true,
        stepNotifications = true,
        snippets = CucumberOptions.SnippetType.CAMELCASE
)
public class layer0 {

}
```

My problem is: I am trying to run a test from Command line, with a specific tag.

For example, based on cucumber.io documentation, it should be:

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@layer0"
```

When running this, I have the following output:

```
     Unknown lifecycle phase ".options=--tags @layer0". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecy
cle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, 
test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy.
```

More stuff that I have tried:

```
mvn test -D"cucumber.filter.tags='@layer0'"

mvn test -Dcucumber.options="@layer0"
```

**Solutions based on:**

[Dcucumber.options, how to have multiple tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34538571/dcucumber-options-how-to-have-multiple-tags)

[-Dcucumber.options ignored with mvn test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64704059/dcucumber-options-ignored-with-mvn-test)

[Why run cucumber tests with tags gives error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73051196/why-run-cucumber-tests-with-tags-gives-error-message)

I think I do some mistakes somewhere, but I cannot figure it out.

So, how can I run a specific tag that is used somewhere in my .feature file?

Thank you, and sorry for the manuscript :)

Comment: It is your command line processor that treats what you type differently than you expect. My guess is powershell on windows

Comment: Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, xerx593

I used powershell, and integrated terminal from IntelliJ, which I belive is still powershell.

I have tried with command prompt, it does not throw any error but the tests are not running with the tag I provide.